# Lightgbm, time-series and spikes repeated on a yearly basis

Tags: time-series, python, boosting, lightgbm

I have a data set (time-series) with the shape {$2190$x$63$}. There are 63 variables, 2 products ($A$ and $B$) worth of 3 years of daily data, thus I have $1095$ observations per product and total of $2190$ observations.

**Important note**: Product $A$ has **spikes** every 30th of December.

I've built a **lightgbm** model which overall works just fine. I've chosen **lightgbm** because the number of products will be much larger, increasing the size of the dataset. Let's say $20$ products, $1095$ observations per product, $63$ variables, which totals $20*1095=21900$ rows and $63$ columns.

**My problem**: `min_data_in_leaf` affects how well **spikes** of the product $A$ are forecasted.

As far as I can tell, when you have a relatively large dataset {$21900$x$63$} (it can go WELL beyond it), `min_data_in_leaf` should be large enough to make sure that your model is not overfitting. The problem is, no matter how many products will be included (expanding my data), large `min_data_in_leaf` will fail to capture these **spikes** because to distinguish them from other observations I need to specify a small value of `min_data_in_leaf`. At least to my understanding.

**My thoughts on it**:

1. I should stick to tuning other parameters that control overfitting and keep `min_data_in_leaf` fairly low;
2. Maybe I need to do more feature engineering? (I've tried, unsuccessfully)

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**Visualisation. 1 year of data (I have 3) + forecasts**:

[image: Comparing models]

**My parameters (early stopping is on)**:

```
lgb_params = {'boosting_type': 'gbdt',
              'objective': 'regression',
              'metric': 'rmse',
              'learning_rate': 0.01,
              'subsample': 0.8,
              'subsample_freq': 1,
              'feature_fraction': 0.6,
              # 'max_depth': -1, 
              'num_leaves': 100,
              'min_data_in_leaf': 30,
              'max_bin': 100,
              'n_estimators': 10000,
              'boost_from_average': False,
              'verbose': -1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, if your objective is to maximize predictive performance, you should choose the hyperparameters that maximize your expected predictive performance (eg. by choosing the parameters which lead to maximal performance on holdout data). It's not common to set hyperparameters by hand unless you have some specific goal in mind. If you see significantly better performance with `min_data_in_leaf:30` than `min_data_in_leaf:100`, go with 30, all other things being equal. No need to overthink it.

To your thoughts...

**1. I should stick to tuning other parameters that control overfitting and keep min_data_in_leaf fairly low**

Never really a bad idea to experiment with more hyperparameters. And in this case, if you know that certain quirks of your dataset will lead to a low value of `min_data_in_leaf`  performing well, it might make extra sense to experiment with other types of regularization. The LightGBM [Parameters Tuning](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters-Tuning.html) page lists around eight other hyperparameters that can reduce overfitting. But again, this should be done in the context of maximizing performance on holdout data. If more regularization leads to a worse predictive model, why are you adding it?

**2. Maybe I need to do more feature engineering? (I've tried, unsuccessfully)**

That would not solve the problem with `min_data_in_leaf`. If you only have 40 observations where `date='Dec 30'` you're only going to have 40 observations where `is_dec_30=True`.

Comment: Sincerely appreciate your answer! Yes, I agree that one should not manually choose parameters, I got mine as a result of CV and decided to play around with some of them to better understand my data. Your answer to my question pertaining feature engineering is particularly insightful, I haven’t thought about it that way. Thank you one more time!